# Error message : Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'dist' does not exist

Tags: webpack, web-deployment, netlify

I'm try to deploy three js site on netlify.
It's showing the deply error message like
Error message : Deploy did not succeed: Deploy directory 'dist' does not exist
Although site is buildedsuccessfully

```
{
  "name": "shuence",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack starter",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --output-public-path=/build/dist  --mode development --progress --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": " Shuence ",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.6.0",
    "ammo.js": "github:kripken/ammo.js",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "stats.js": "^0.17.0",
    "three": "^0.117.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the build command on `package.json` to `nuxt generate` or in the netlify build settings use `nuxt generate` instead of using `yarn build` in the build command.

then set `target: 'serverless'` on `nuxt.config` file.